# Issue with understanding python bedmas

Tags: python, math

I'm doing a mock test and I am getting most of these bedmas questions wrong...

```
a) 25 / 4 + 4 * 10 % 3

b) 25 - 7 * 3 + 12 / 3

c) 17 % 3 * 2 - 12 + 15


a) 
6.25 + 4 * 1
10.25

b)
25 - 21 + 4
8

c)
2 * 2 - 12 + 15
4 + 3
7
```

I've only managed to get one right (c). Please help.

Comment: Thanks to @Grijesh, http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1439189

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are dealing with integers not floats and so you must use integer math not float math.

In `integer` math: `5 / 2` is `2` not `2.5` since the `.5` gets truncated. If you wanted to get `2.5`, you would have to do: `5.0 / 2.0` or `float(5) / float(2)`.

(Note: As @Grijesh pointed out, in python3 (5/2) actually yields 2.5). However, if you are using any other language, I believe it is as I have described above (python2.7 gives 2))

As follows:

```
a) 25 / 4 + 4 * 10 % 3
b) 25 - 7 * 3 + 12 / 3
c) 17 % 3 * 2 - 12 + 15


a) 
6 + 4 * 1
10

b)
25 - 21 + 4
8

c)
2 * 2 - 12 + 15
4 + 3
7
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: in Python 3 `5 / 2 != 2`

Comment: @Grijesh, Thank you. Will incorporate into answer now.

Comment: you can use [this post](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1439189) It advises that if you use old Python  then you can use `from __future__ import division `

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, I have posted it as a comment on the question since the exercise the OP is doing is probably meant to teach about the differences in human and computer integer math.

Comment: yes, your answer is helpful.

Comment: I made a stupid mistake for question b. For question a, I get 7.25 using Python (3.3.4)

Comment: @SuccessfulFail, Surprisingly, b also took me the longest to figure out. :P

Comment: @SuccessfulFail, If my answer was helpful, would you mind accepting it ? Thanks and Good Luck